# Convert Elm Html nodes to string output

Tags: html, elm

I have a `viewFunc` that returns some HTML. I would like to validate its return value. I wrote a test case using `elm-test`.

```
viewFunc |> Expect.equal (span [] [ text "hello world"])
```

It works well as long as my test case passes. However, when it fails, I get the following error:

```
    <internals>
    ╷
    │ Expect.equal
    ╵
    <internals>
```

It's not helpful at all. How could I have a more meaningful error message? Is there a way to stringify `Html` nodes? I [looked around in the documentation of `elm-html`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/html/latest/) but haven't found anything.

Comment: This doesn't seem possible in general. It doesn't even seem generally feasible to compare Html nodes. For example, how would you compare nodes with event handlers? What if the handlers are anonymous lambdas whose code is identical but close over different values? Are they "equal"? And how would you convert those to strings in a way that illustrates the difference?

Comment: Also note that is why elm-test includes the [Test.Html.* modules](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-explorations/test/latest/Test-Html-Query).

Comment: @glennsl Fair enough, I understand your point. However currently it's possible to compare nodes, my test case runs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than comparing entire chunks of `Html msg` together, you'll get better results using the [`Test.Html.Query`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-explorations/test/latest/Test-Html-Query) module (and corresponding [`Test.Html.Selector`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-explorations/test/latest/Test-Html-Selector) and [`Test.Html.Event`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-explorations/test/latest/Test-Html-Event) modules). This allows you to create more targeted tests (e.g. testing whether a certain element has certain text or a certain class, rather than testing the entirety of the HTML structure). And the test failures do provide much more context to help you debug.

I've built [an example on Ellie](https://ellie-app.com/fT3VMjdKkkFa1), here's the basics of what a test might look like:

```
test "Button has correct count" <|
    \() ->
        viewFunc
            |> Query.fromHtml
            |> Query.has [ Selector.text "hello world" ]
```

The results in the console for a failure would be:

```
> Hello World

    ▼ Query.fromHtml

        <div>
            Hello World!
        </div>


    ▼ Query.has [ text "hello world" ]

    > has text "hello world"
```